# How to launch gnome-terminal from command line and duplicate environment variables?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is there a way to launch a gnome-terminal from the command line (i.e., using the /usr/bin/gnome-terminal command) and have the new terminal inherit the environment variables and other set variables of terminal from which the command was run?  The scenario is thus:

1. Open a terminal
2. Set some variables
3. Set some environment variables
4. Launch an executable that needs the variables and the environment variables of the current terminal in a new terminal

Thoughts?

Comment: This is really a shell question, not a gnome-terminal question. What shell are you using?

Comment: This is all happening from a c shell script (I guess you could put that as step 1.5 - execute a c shell script that performs the following actions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This turned out to be a gnome-terminal issue.  When launching the gnome-terminal, specifying the `--disable-factory` option provides the following directive:

"Do not register with the activation name server, and do not reuse an already running GNOME terminal process" (*gnome-terminal man page*)

Specifying this option was required in order to inherit the environment of the previous shell.

Comment: GNOME Terminal 3.40.3 says: Option “--disable-factory” is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal. What we can do instead is export variables, as suggested on [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286002/how-do-i-open-gnome-terminal-with-new-enviroment-variables?rq=1), or [my related blog post](https://github.com/vorburger/vorburger.ch-Notes/blob/develop/linux/gnome-terminal.md).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `export` against the variables in the other shell if you want child processes to inherit them.

Comment: This is along the right lines, except setenv has to be used rather than export because it is a c shell.  However, I'm still having a problem.  If I'm in a tsch and set an environment variable and then switch to csh, it works fine.  However, if I'm in csh, set an environment variable, and switch to tcsh (in a new gnome-terminal), the environment variables are not propagated into the tsch.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately C-shells are not really my strength; I do much better with `sh` derivatives.